# Does PDO::commit throw an exception on failure?

Tags: php, mysql

When `PDO:commit` fails, does it throw an exception? Or just return `false`?

The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php) don't mention anything on exceptions, but one of the comments says it does. I couldn't figure out a way to test it myself.

Comment: `Returns FALSE on failure. ` Seems pretty clear. And none of the examples have a `try/catch` block so it's safe to say it only returns `FALSE` when it fails

Comment: I'd wager the fact both comments on the page refer to exceptions being thrown when there's an error (such as database crashing during the transaction)?

Answer (score 1):

From php_pdo.c, it appears the commit method can in fact throw exceptions. At the very least, when there is no active transaction.

```
static PHP_METHOD(PDO, commit)
{
    pdo_dbh_t *dbh = Z_PDO_DBH_P(getThis());

    if (zend_parse_parameters_none() == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }
    PDO_CONSTRUCT_CHECK;

    if (!dbh->in_txn) {
        zend_throw_exception_ex(php_pdo_get_exception(), 0, "There is no active transaction");
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    if (dbh->methods->commit(dbh)) {
        dbh->in_txn = 0;
        RETURN_TRUE;
    }

    PDO_HANDLE_DBH_ERR();
    RETURN_FALSE;
}
```